# Always get Nil Returned When Querying Customers with Shopify_API Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I am trying to get a list of all customers for my shopify dev instance, but I always get Nil returned no matter how I structure my Customer API call using the Shopify_API Gem.

`customers = ShopifyAPI::Customer.all` returns `nil`, as do variations of `.find` with `params`. Whereas the example `products = ShopifyAPI::Product.all` returns all the `products`. According to the docs I should be able to get Customers back but I cant.. I have 5 in my shopify instance.

I set the app up to be a private app and set the base.site for the shopifyAPI like so ShopifyAPI::Base.site = "https://apikey:password@storename.myshopify.com"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My customer finder always works... I use a slightly different one from you. Use this as an example to get you going.

```
 ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(:first, :from => :search, :params => { :q => "email:#{customer['email']}" })
```

Comment: Thanks, after about the 10th time of re-setting up my rails and shopify API stuff. It seems to work now. Even with my original Customer.all call. I honestly have no idea what fixed it, could of been a gem outdated or something like that, not installed correctly. Im assuming it had something to do with Activeresource gem in some way. Thank you for the help though I appreciate it.